# Why my code for displaying user profile in Django isn't working?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-users

I'm learning Django and I'm making a website that includes registering and creating your own profile. When you're logged in you can view other users profiles and by clicking on their picture it redirects you to their profile site.

The problem is: the picture redirects you to the right url but it shows base template rather than the one that I want
I checked some websites and even chat gpt for help but it wasn't successful

I'll only show important parts of my code but if sth missing just let me know and I'll add it. Here's the code for 'urls.py':

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.templatetags.static import static


app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile_list/', views.profile_list, name='profile_list'),
    path('user_profile/<int:user_id>/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]
```

'views.py'

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import RegisterForm, UserProfileForm, MessageForm
from .models import UserProfile, Message
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('app:index')
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form':form})


def profile_list(request):
    profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'profile_list.html', {'profiles': profiles})


def user_profile(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user_id=user_id)
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'profile': profile})
```

'models.py'

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'profile_pics/user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path,
        default='profile_pics/default.jpeg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Base template
'base.html'

```
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
      {% load static %}
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static 'style.css' %}' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Allison&family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@200&family=Ephesis&family=Gwendolyn&family=Lato:wght@100;400&family=Lovers+Quarrel&family=Mea+Culpa&family=MonteCarlo&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&family=Pinyon+Script&family=Qwigley&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&family=Whisper&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <nav>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:profile_list' %}">Strona główna</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:messages' %}">Listy</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:profile' %}">Profil</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:logout' %}">Wyloguj się</a></li>
          </ul>
      {% else %}
          <ul>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:index' %}">Strona główna</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:login' %}">Zaloguj się</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'app:register' %}">Zarejestruj się</a></li>
          </ul>
      {% endif %}
      <img src="{% static 'border1.png' %}"/>
  </nav>
  <body>
      <section>
          {% block body %}
            <h1>Witaj w aplikacji Czat!</h1>

          {% endblock %}
      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Template with list of profiles
'profile_list.html'

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>Profile użytkowników</h1>
  <ul class="profiles">
      {% for profile in profiles %}
        <li>
            <a href="/user_profile/{{ profile.user.id }}/">
                <img src="{{ profile.profile_pic.url }}" alt="Zdjęcie użytkownika {{ request.user.username }}" style="height: 150px; width:150px">
            </a>
            {{ profile.user.username }}
            {{ profile.user.id }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Before `<a href="/user_profile/{{ profile.user.id }}/">` I had `<a href="{% url 'user_profile' profile.user.id %}">` and it showed and error that there is no valid view such as 'user_profile. After changing it, clicking some picture redirects me to the right url e.x. 127.0.0.1:8000/user_profile/1/ but like I said before it doesn't show chosen user's profile but the index page

Specific user profile template
'user_profile.html'

I'm not sure if it's correct e.x. if `{{ user.userprofile.username }}` should look differently to specify that I want to show specific user's info. I tried different variations and I don't know what's the best option but right now I think it's not the main problem

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_pic.url }}" alt="Zdjęcie profilowe użytkownika {{ request.user.userprofile.username }}">
    <h2>{{ user.userprofile.username }}</h2>
    <p>{{ user.userprofile.bio }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I think that's all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your **profile_list.html** you have to include the app name since you defined it in your **urls.py**, `app_name = 'app'`:
**profiles_list.html**

```py
<a href="{% url 'app:user_profile' profile.user.id %}">
```

Next, in your **user_profile.html** it should be

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="{{ profile.profile_pic.url }}" alt="Zdjęcie profilowe użytkownika {{ profile.user.username }}">
    <h2>{{ profile.user.username }}</h2>
    <p>{{ profile.bio }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Why?  Because in your `user_profile` view you send `profile` in your context, `return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'profile': profile})`.  Now, profile is a `UserProfile` object you defined in your **models.py** with fields of `bio` and `profile_pic`, and to access the user name you do `profile.user.username`.

Comment: thank you, I also found a mistake, there should me {% block body %} in one place and I wrote {% block content %}, now it works :)